# graphic card size for efficient running of Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How much graph card memory I need to run the Gazebo efficiently? Is 1GB nVidia enough?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63087/graphic-card-size-for-efficient-running-of-gazebo/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably but it is not that GPU memory dependent, it should support OpenGL. Gazebo is more CPU dependent.
See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements) for a small list of supported hardware.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1